# Compensation Year-End Planning VBA Script

Tags: vba, excel

I have a pre-planning file for year-end review that does a lot of index/match formulas and `IF` statement formulas based on certain parameters when referencing increases in various types of pay/incentive pay.

```
Sub Update()


'File Paths
Dim Preplan As String: Preplan = "M:\PrePlanning_Template.xlsm"
Dim PS_Export As String: PS_Export = "M:\PS_Export.xlsx"

'Open WB's
Dim PP_WB As Workbook: Set PP_WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Preplan, Password:="")
Dim PS_WB As Workbook: Set PS_WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=PS_Export)

Dim PP_WS As Worksheet: Set PP_WS = PP_WB.Sheets("2017 Pre-Planning Emp Detail")
Dim PS_WS As Worksheet: Set PS_WS = PS_WB.Sheets("ps")

Dim lrAR As Long, lrAS As Long, lrAX As Long

LastRow = PP_WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = PS_WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

PP_WB.Activate

PP_WS.Range("AE2").Formula = "=INDEX([PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$K:$K,MATCH(A2,[PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$A:$A,0))"
PP_WS.Range("AE2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AE2:AE" & LastRow)

PP_WS.Range("AF2").Formula = "=INDEX([PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$H:H,MATCH(A2,[PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$A:$A,0))"
PP_WS.Range("AF2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AF2:AF" & LastRow)

PP_WS.Range("AG2").Formula = "=INDEX([PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$AX:AX,MATCH(A2,[PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$A:$A,0))"
PP_WS.Range("AG2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AG2:AG" & LastRow)

PP_WS.Range("AH2").Formula = "=INDEX([PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$O:O,MATCH(A2,[PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$A:$A,0))"
PP_WS.Range("AH2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AH2:AH" & LastRow)


PP_WS.Range("AI2").Formula = "=INDEX([PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$P:P,MATCH(A2,[PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$A:$A,0))"
PP_WS.Range("AI2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AI2:AI" & LastRow)

PP_WS.Range("AE:AI").Copy
PP_WS.Range("AE:AI").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


With PP_WS.Range("AG:AG")
     .Replace What:="Assistant Vice President", Replacement:="AVP", _
        LookAt:=xlPart
     .Replace What:="Vice President", Replacement:="VP", LookAt:= _
        xlPart
     .Replace What:="Sr. VP", Replacement:="SVP", LookAt:= _
        xlPart
     .Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:= _
        xlPart
End With

PS_WB.Activate

PP_WS.Range("AE:AE").Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole

PS_WS.Range("AH:AH").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

'fills to last row in PS report'
PS_WS.Range("AH2").Formula = "=AD2+AG2"
PS_WS.Range("AH2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AH2:AH" & lastrow2)
PS_WS.Range("AH2").Range("AH1") = "Variable Comp"


PS_WB.Close savechanges:=False



''if there is an "X" in column F (sr. manager), then do a VLOOKUP, if not then do the calc'
PP_WS.Range("AR2").Formula = "=IF(F2=""X"",VLOOKUP(A2,[PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$A:$AH,34,FALSE),(AS2+AU2+AX2))"
PP_WS.Range("AR2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AR2:AR" & LastRow)

'if there isn't an "X" in column F, then do a VLOOKUP, if not keep the calc'
PP_WS.Range("AS2").Formula = "=IF(F2="""",VLOOKUP(A2,[PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$A:$AD,30,FALSE),(AR2-AX2))"
PP_WS.Range("AS2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AS2:AS" & LastRow)

PP_WS.Range("AX2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,[PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$A:$AG,33,FALSE)"
PP_WS.Range("AX2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AX2:AX" & LastRow)

'PP_WS.Range("AX:AX").Copy
'PP_WS.Range("AX:AX").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Filter section for Sr. Leaders'

PP_WS.Cells.AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="<>"

lrAX = Cells(Rows.Count, 50).End(xlUp).Row
    With Range(Cells(2, 50), Cells(lrAX, 50))
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-6]<=300000,RC[-6]*0.3,IF(AND(RC[-6]>300000,RC[-6]<=500000),((RC[-6]-300000)*0.35)+90000,IF(AND(RC[-6]>500000,RC[-6]<=1000000),((RC[-6]-500000)*0.4)+160000,IF(RC[-6]>1000000,((RC[-6]-1000000)*0.45)+360000,))))"
    End With

'Second filter section'


'selects cell AS2, designates that as current region, autofilters column F'
PP_WS.Cells.AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="<>"


lrAS = Cells(Rows.Count, 45).End(xlUp).Row
    With Range(Cells(2, 45), Cells(lrAS, 45))
    .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[5]"
End With

PP_WS.Cells.AutoFilter field:=5


PP_WS.Range("AR2").AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=""


'   Find last row with data in column 44
    lrAR = Cells(Rows.Count, 44).End(xlUp).Row
    With Range(Cells(2, 44), Cells(lrAR, 44))
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]+RC[3]+RC[6]"
    End With

PP_WS.Cells.AutoFilter



PP_WS.Range("AS2").AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:="<>"


    With Range(Cells(2, 45), Cells(lrAS, 45))
    .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[5]"

End With

Cells.AutoFilter
Cells.AutoFilter







Application.ScreenUpdating = True



End Sub
```

What I'm curious about is any tactic that I can deploy in order to condense this script to make it run faster. It works fine, but I'm sure there is repetitive with/end with referencing and subtle things like that that are unnecessary. I would like this to also serve as a learning experience for me to make my code more elegant.

Comment: Do you need the formulas on your final product or just the values?

Comment: @Raystafarian, formulas need to be housed in the report

Answer (score 1):

First, your indenting is all weird. Sometimes that's a result of copy/paste into CodeReview - but it's worth pointing out anyway. Make sure *everything* is indented at least 1 tab and each level is indented one further tab. Then any labels you may have are not indented. [Rubberduck-VBA](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) has a method for doing this for you. It's a neat add-in, maintained by users on CodeReview - give it a look.

---

#### Sheet Activity

When using VBA, it's best to not need to do *anything* on the worksheet (like `.Activate` or `.Select` and it's usually much faster if you don't build on the sheet, but instead build in an array and write to sheet all at once.

Right now you have `.Activate`, `.Copy` and `.Paste` - all intrinsically slow. You also have some `.Replace` as well as `.Autofill` and others.

Since you didn't turn off `Application.Calculate`, when you do this

> ```
> PP_WS.Range("AE2").Formula = "=INDEX([PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$K:$K,MATCH(A2,[PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$A:$A,0))"
> PP_WS.Range("AE2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AE2:AE" & LastRow)
> ```

It's going to calculate all these formulas as they fill. The best way to avoid this would be simply putting

```
Application.Calculate = xlManual
```

At the top, and at the end setting it back to `xlAutomatic`. But, I think there's a better way to do it.

Build your ranges, create the formula base, write the series and then print them all to sheet. So something *similar* to

```
Dim formulaArray As Variant
ReDim formulaArray(2 To lastrow)
For i = 2 To lastrow
    formulaArray = "=INDEX([PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$K:$K,MATCH(A" & i & ",[PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$A:$A,0))"
Next

Dim fillRange As Range
Set fillRange = PP_WS.Range(PP_WS.Range("AE2"), PP_WS.Range("AE" & lastrow))
fillRange.Formula = formulaArray
```

See what I mean by building your formulas and then writing them all at once?

#### Variables

Your variables are all declared and given types, which is great, but their naming could be improved. [Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) have `camelCase` for local variables and `PascalCase` for other variables and names. It's also a good clue that if you have a *digit* in your variable - it's not named great.

You have `LastRow` and `lastrow2`. If we ignore the fact that these are actually the same number, they aren't consistent with naming conventions *or* even *each other*. `lastRow` or `sourceLastRow` and then `targetLastRow` or something would seem better.

Here -

> ```
> Dim Preplan As String: Preplan = "M:\PrePlanning_Template.xlsm"
> Dim PS_Export As String: PS_Export = "M:\PS_Export.xlsx"
> ```

Good job creating variables for these strings, but it's even better if you created *constant* variables -

```
Const PREPLAN_PATH As String = "M:\PrePlanning_Template.xlsm"
Const EXPORT_PATH As String = "M:\PS_Export.xlsm"
```

Since they never change, they are constants. And they will stick out. Also, in my example above, I would build the formulas using constants:

```
Const FORMULA_BEGINNING As String = "=INDEX([PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$K:$K,MATCH(A"
Const FORMULA_ENDING As String = ",[PS_Export.xlsx]ps!$A:$A,0))"
For i = 2 To lastrow
    formulaArray = FORMULA_BEGINNING & i & FORMULA_ENDING
Next
```

See how that looks cleaner? I'd also probably not use something like `A:A` and instead explicitly state the range.

#### Replace

So since you are finding and replacing something that already exists, I don't really have any basis to say you should do it a different way. But maybe you have a different way to build that. However, when using a blank e.g.

> ```
> PP_WS.Range("AE:AE").Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
> ```

You should use the build-in constant `vbNullString`

```
PP_WS.Range("AE:AE").Replace What:="0", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
```

I'd also give your sub a better name than **Update** - name it what it does - updating pre-planning or something similar?

Anyway, you can extrapolate these recommendations to the rest of the procedure.

I also might create a `BuildFormula` function for building the formulas, maybe have it take arguments so you can pass what kind of formula to it and reuse it throughout the code.